Showing the following error when trying to add channel to wordpress website
this is the error bug i'm receiving. Can i please get some advise on how to fix this issue please?
{
  "vct": "0.000",
  "vd": "NaN",
  "vpl": "",
  "vbu": "",
  "vbs": "",
  "vpa": "1",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "0",
  "vns": "0",
  "vec": "null",
  "vemsg": "",
  "vvol": "1",
  "vdom": "1",
  "vsrc": "0",
  "vw": "0",
  "vh": "0",
  "state": "80",
  "debug_error": "{\"errorCode\":\"api.invalidparam\",\"errorMessage\":\"An error occurred. Please try again later.\",\"SP\":\"GENERIC_WITHOUT_LINK\",\"po\":\"\",\"DM\":\"invalidVideodata.1;a6s.0\",\"tA\":2,\"cpn\":\"hXbWb-AS5YE6OqsB\"}",
  "relative_loudness": "NaN",
  "user_qual": 0,
  "release_version": "youtube.player.web_20240826_01_RC00",
  "0sz": "true",
  "op": "",
  "yof": "true",
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "ANGLE_(AMD,_AMD_Radeon_(TM)_Graphics_(0x000015E7)_Direct3D11_vs_5_0_ps_5_0,_D3D11)",
  "debug_playbackQuality": "unknown",
  "debug_date": "Thu Aug 29 2024 13:36:16 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)",
  "origin": "https://www.youtube.com",
  "timestamp": 1724934976330
}

I'm not very technical, but i've setup the youtube API to run youtube V3. But we keep getting the following error pasted above when we try to add my channel.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What code did you add on your WordPress website? - [edit] your question and add the code.

I'm using Revolution Slider 6 pro. Where we add the channel, then it shows the channel feed onto the page. But it's not showing the feed. (But shows seperate playlists, when each is added seperately)

That sounds like a issue with "Revolution Slider 6 pro" - contact customer support for that.
